# get all javascript timezone as per entered date

Tags: javascript, html, timezone

how can I get all time zone detail as per date.
For example : I entered date 23/06/2015 and  I get all standard time zone detail as per DST / Non DST for that date. like at this time America/Godthab (GMT-03:00) Greenland with DST and Asia/Baku ((GMT+04:00) Baku, Tbilisi, Yerevan) with Non DST.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript getTimezoneOffset() method:

> The getTimezoneOffset() method returns the time difference between UTC time and local time, in minutes.
>   For example, If your time zone is GMT+2, -120 will be returned.

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) for information.

You can also use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), it looks perfect.

Comment: My question is to list down all timezone display name like (GMT+04:00) Baku, Tbilisi, Yerevan) , (GMT-03:00) Greenland  etc as per the entered date. All of it I think there are 79 time zones differently. 

Just need to confirm where is it predefined function available or we have to iterate each timezone and check where it is fall in DST or not ans display it value.

Comment: You can get all zone names with [this](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/) and then use momentjs functions to setup the information that you want.
I know only this method, check [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) for information and usage